# android bitmap write ARGB_8888 on read RGB_565 (pre ICS)

Tags: android, bitmap

I am successfully cropping a Bitmap generated from Camera preview and I am saving the generated small bitmap to sdcard. When creating the both big and cropped Bitmaps, I am configuring them to [Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html). But when I am loading that image from sdcard, the configuration of the Bitmap is changed to RGB_565. I need it be ARGB_8888. This happens on pre-ICS devices (I don't know what to say about HoneyComb as I don't have one):

1. Motorola Defy (2.3.4)
2. Sony Ericsson S (2.3.4)
3. Sony Ericsson Live Walkman (2.3.4)
4. Samsung Galaxy Mini (2.2.1)
5. Samsung Spica (2.2)

What is weird is after I am creating the cropped bitmap, I am querying for its config and I am seeing in the log to be ARGB_8888.

On all ICS and JellyBean devices that I have tested against, I am not seeing this, as the Bitmap loaded is always ARGB_8888 configured.

Below is how I am cropping and configuring the image given the array of bytes from camera:

```
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(byte[]... params) {
            /***
             * Will return the file name where we created the image
             * */
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss");
            String fileName = sdf.format(new Date()) + ".jpeg";
            File cameraRoot = Utils.getFileCacheDir(context, WIMSConstants.FileCacheDirs.CAMERA_CAPTURED);
            if (!cameraRoot.exists() || !cameraRoot.isDirectory()) {
                if (!cameraRoot.mkdir()) {
                    Log.e("WIMSOcrCamera", "Unable to create folder name " + cameraRoot.getAbsolutePath());
                    return null;
                }
            }
            /**
             * The target file name where to write
             * **/
            File targetFile = new File(cameraRoot, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                byte[] cameraByteArray = params[0];
                Options opts = new Options();
                opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cameraByteArray, 0, cameraByteArray.length, opts);
                /**
                 * Below log prints 'ARGB_8888' no matter the OS I am running
                 * */
                Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Big camera image config: " + bitmap.getConfig());
                fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
                /**
                 * screenDims is a two array giving the full size image (full screen size)
                 * **/
                int fullSizeWidth = screenDims[0];
                int fullSizeHeight = screenDims[1];
                /**
                 * viewPortrect is a Rect that defines the area from the screen that I would like to crop.
                 * 
                 * rectLeft, rectTop, rectWidth and rectHeight are the desired dimensions of the cropped image relative to the above created bitmap (bitmap).
                 * */
                int rectLeft = bitmap.getWidth() * viewPortRect.left / fullSizeWidth;
                int rectTop = bitmap.getHeight() * viewPortRect.top / fullSizeHeight;
                int rectWidth = bitmap.getWidth() * viewPortRect.width() / fullSizeWidth;
                int rectHeight = bitmap.getHeight() * viewPortRect.height() / fullSizeHeight;

                int[] array = new int[rectWidth * rectHeight];

                bitmap.getPixels(array, 0, rectWidth, rectLeft, rectTop, rectWidth, rectHeight);
                bitmap.recycle();
                /**
                 * Hurray! we have the cropped image int[] pixel data
                 * **/
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(array, rectWidth, rectHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
                /**
                 * Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888.equals(bitmap.getConfig()) ALWAYS evaluates to true no matter the device OS I am running.
                 * **/
                Log.d(TAG_LOG, "generated smaller file ... config: " + bitmap.getConfig() + "; is onfig.ARGB_8888 equals: " + (Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888.equals(bitmap.getConfig())));
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                fos.flush();
                bitmap.recycle();
                Log.d(TAG_LOG, "DONE creating the cropped image ...");
                return targetFile.getAbsolutePath();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG_LOG, null, ex);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                Log.e(TAG_LOG, null, th);
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Loading the image from SDCard, given its fileURI (from a Service):

```
Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), fileUri);
/**
 * "RGB_565" for pre-ICS always
 * **/
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "bitmap config: " + bmp.getConfig());
```

Is this a known issue? Is there any work-around except for passing the cropped bitmap through intent to the final receiver?

Thanks!

Comment: same behavior for CompressFormat.PNG ?

Comment: Haven't tried with PNG. I am using the images for OCR recognition, for this reason I need the image quality to be the best. I am not sure, but JPEGs quality is better than PNG? ...will give it a try with PNG though and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: JPEG is the worst you can possibly have!

Comment: Setting to PNG compress saved it - even though I would be very curious why. And indeed PNG is much better than JPEG :). @SatelliteSD, I don't like having un-answered question, so please post your answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `CompressFormat.JPEG` to `CompressFormat.PNG`.

Comment: Do you happen to know also why? :)

Comment: No. I could imagine, that JPEG dropps the alpha channel, but this would reduce only to RGB_888. Since your results are RGB_565 I would assume that JPEG is a 16 bit format, but that is only guessing.